# Create view with timestamp of last modified datetime from base tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-view

I have two tables which don't have datetime columns. I need to create a view on top of these two tables along with lastupdatedtime column, when it is new record it will store getdate() function, if there is update in any table then latestupdatedtime should be there is there no changes to both tables then in lastupdatedate should not change.

For example - table A:

| Sno | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sai |
| 2 | venkat |

Table B

| Sno | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hyd |
| 2 | chennai |

View with table A, B

| Sno | Name | City | updatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sai | hyd | 10:00 AM |
| 2 | venkat | chennai | 10:00 AM |

For example if there is update, insert in table B around 11:00 AM
table B

| Sno | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hyd |
| 2 | Pune |
| 3 | delhi |

and insert in table A around 11:00 AM

Table A

| Sno | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sai |
| 2 | venkat |
| 3 | Siva |

then final view should be as

| Sno | Name | City | updatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sai | hyd | 10:00 AM |
| 2 | venkat | Pune | 11:00 AM |
| 3 | Siva | delhi | 11:00 AM |

Is it possible to create a view query like this?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: The server can't come up with data that it doesn't have. Add some autoutilized datetime column into the tables structures.